# Android Studio, Using a variable to another Activiy

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText nama;
    Button OK;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListenerButton_OK();
    }

    private void addListenerButton_OK() {
        nama=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_NamaAnda);
        OK=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_OK);

        OK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                

                if(nama.getText().toString().equals("Fredy") || nama.getText().toString().equals("Oktafianus") || nama.getText().toString().equals("Markus") || nama.getText().toString().equals("fredy") || nama.getText().toString().equals("oktafianus") || nama.getText().toString().equals("markus")){
                    Intent Clicked_OK=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Game.class);                   
                    startActivity(Clicked_OK);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Error : "+nama.getText()+" Bukan nama depan anda!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I need help here!

I created `MainActiviy` and a second Activity called `Game`. I want to send EditText `nama` to the second Activity. I want to use `nama` in my second activity.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the purpose of using "nama" in second activity? If you only want the value of edittext, then you can send the value of edittext as a string in the intent used to call second activity and then get the value from bundle in the second activity, then use it.

Comment: Kau boleh ganti `equals()` dengan `equalsIgnoreCase()` supaya mana2 huruf besar akan diabaikan, tak perlu declare banyak kali macam "Fredy", "fRedy", "frEdy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
Intent Clicked_OK = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Game.class);
Clicked_OK.putExtra("nama",nama.getText().toString());
startActivity(Clicked_OK);
```

On Game class onCreate method get "nama" from this way,

```
String nama =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("nama");
```

An Intent is a messaging object you can use to request an action from another app component.

**Extras** Key-value pairs that carry additional information required to accomplish the requested action.

Answer (score 2):

Pass it in bundle like below .

```
private void addListenerButton_OK() {
    nama=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_NamaAnda);
    OK=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_OK);
    OK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(nama.getText().toString().equals("Fredy")||nama.getText().toString().equals("Oktafianus")||nama.getText().toString().equals("Markus")
                    ||nama.getText().toString().equals("fredy")||nama.getText().toString().equals("oktafianus")||nama.getText().toString().equals("markus")){
                Intent Clicked_OK=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Game.class);
                Clicked_OK.putExtra("NAME", nama.getText());
                startActivity(Clicked_OK);
            }else{

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Error : "+nama.getText()+" Bukan nama depan anda!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then in game activity OnCreate method, get name like this ,

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent!=null){
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        String name  = bundle.getString("NAME");
    }
```